# Install Ionic behind a corporate firewall

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to install ionic (i need version 1) and cordova but i am behind a firewall and still could not install.

I set the proxy with npm  config:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Try to run : npm install -g ionic

But a proxy authentication was required.

C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\myapp (master) (myapp_v01@1.0.0)
λ `npm install -g ionic`
npm ERR! code E407
npm ERR! 407 Proxy Authentication Required: ionic@latest

So i try : npm --proxy `http://myuser:mypassword@proxy.mycompany.rs.gov.br:myportnumber install -g ionic`

But still gives me an error:

```
npm ERR! code E407
npm ERR! 407 Proxy Authentication Required: ionic@latest
```

What can i do to install Ionic behind a firewall ?

Answer (score 0):

After a while it worked for me :

```
$ npm config set proxy http://login:pass@host:port
$ npm config set https-proxy http://login:pass@host:port this worked for me.
```